# ContextMenu doesn't invoke delete in managedbean

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, java-ee-6

I'm new in jsf and I want to use contextMenu of primeface for delete method.But the delete methode is never invoked. here are parts of code.I don't know where i mistake

```
  <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="bon"  widgetVar="bonTable" value="#{bonEssenceBean.allBonEssence}" rowKey="#{bon.idBon}" selection="#{bonEssenceBean.bonEssence}" selectionMode="single" sortMode="single" rows="10" paginator="true"  paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,25">    
  <f:facet name="header">
          <p:outputPanel>  
               <h:outputText value="Search:" style="Height:30px"/>  
               <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="bonTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
          </p:outputPanel> 
       </f:facet> 

        <!--  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bonEssence.updateBon}" />  -->
  <!--  <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages" />  -->

        <p:column sortBy="#{bon.idBon}" headerText="ID Bon" filterBy="#{bon.idBon}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 

           #{bon.idBon}

        </p:column>  

        <p:column sortBy="#{bon.vehicule.immat}" headerText="Vehicule:" filterBy="#{bon.vehicule.immat}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
            #{bon.vehicule.immat} 
        </p:column>  

        <p:column sortBy="#{bon.quantite}" headerText="Quantité:" filterBy="#{bon.quantite}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
           #{bon.quantite}
        </p:column>  

        <p:column sortBy="#{bon.prix}" headerText="Prix" filterBy="#{bon.prix}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 

            #{bon.prix}   

        </p:column>  


        <p:column sortBy="#{bon.dateBon}" headerText="Date" filterBy="#{bon.dateBon}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
           #{bon.dateBon} 
        </p:column> 
        <p:column>  
           <p:commandButton value="Imprimer"  icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="printDialog.show()" >
           <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bonEssenceBean.bonEssence}" value="#{bon}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
           </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
         <p:column>  
           <h:commandButton  value="Delete" update="dataTable" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{bonEssenceBean.deleteBo}" >
           <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bonEssenceBean.bonEssence}" value="#{bon}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
           </h:commandButton>
        </p:column>           

   <!--  <h:column headerText="delete">  
         <h:commandLink id="Delete"    actionListener="#{bonEssenceBean.deleteBon}"> 
            <h:outputText value="Delete" /> 
         <f:param id="deleteId"  name="id"  value="#{bonEssence.idBon}" />
          </h:commandLink> 
          </h:column>--> 

    </p:dataTable> 



</h:form>
```

managed

```
public void deleteBon(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println("delete");
    essenceService.deleteBon(bonEssence);
}
```

and deleteBon never invoked

Answer (score 0):

If you dont gonna use the ActionEvent, then you can try this:

```
<h:commandLink id="Delete"    action="#{bonEssenceBean.deleteBon()}">

public void deleteBon(){
System.out.println("delete");
essenceService.deleteBon(bonEssence);
}
```